# How can I legally put number plate on without repairing bumper?

Tags: body-work

[image]
Bumper has fallen off and plastic is cracked in places you can't just put a bolt on and put it back in place.

I asked a police officer if I can remove the bumper and put a number plate in window and he said its illegal(is he right cos I've seen others do it).

If so where can I mount the number plate and be legally able to drive in uk?  Can I, and is it possible to mount it on the radiator or somewhere else?  I will eventually get the bumper fixed, but until I get it repaired, want a quick fix so I can drive it.

Thanks

Comment: Can you tie it to the horizontal bar visible behind the broken valence? Or glue it to the front of the bonnet (hood)?

Comment: I'd probably recommend cable ties on some surface that lets you position the plate vertically, like the front crash bar.

Comment: @WeatherVane the bonnet would make it diagnol which sounds illegal.  it needs to be horizontal it seems.

Comment: I think you mean vertical. The question makes no sense until you remove the damaged part so that the front can be seen. What is wrong with my other suggestion?

Comment: @WeatherVane do u mean with zip ties?  so ill have to make holes in the bumper front and tie it around the bar?  wouldnt that be sturdy? it seems the whole bumper will be hanging of zip ties?

Comment: No, I mean throw away the bumper and fix the plate with ties or string or sticky tape (although I have seen one fixed with ties). If the number plate was fixed with screws then it has holes already. If the ties are not long enough you can link several together, or use string. If it was fixed with sticky tape you can drill some holes in the plate. If you don't like that, the cost of a new number plate later, is trifling next to the cost of the broken front.

Comment: Two choices: fix it properly and drive it **or** don’t fix and don’t drive as it will be dangerous for other road users - the police can stop you, fine you and possibly take the car.

Answer (score 2):

You intend to remove the bumper and use the car.

[Alephzero's answer](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/75018/29437) gives legislation governing the visibility of number plates (basically, vertical and clearly visible).

Your car must not pose an undue danger to other road users. Of course, any car hitting a pedestrian or cyclist is Not A Good Thing, but if the absence of a bumper exposes parts which will cause greater injuries than when the bumper is present, you may fall foul of police or VOSA. Construction & Use [Regulation 100(1)](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/1986/1078/regulation/100/made) is rather widely-drawn. Note also [MoT section 6.1.4](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/mot-inspection-manual-for-private-passenger-and-light-commercial-vehicles/6-body-structure-and-attachments#section-6-1-4) — your vehicle will fail an MoT test with the bumper in its current state or removed, and the dangerous state of the vehicle might be an offence under [Section 40A of the RTA1988](http://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/1988/52/section/40A). You ought also to consider your insurance, as using a vehicle in a dangerous condition might invalidate it.

All of that said, perhaps without the bumper there is still somewhere that the existing plate can be fixed temporarily in much the same position as with the bumper. There appears to be some sort of horizontal bar which might suffice.

If that fails, then getting a flexible/self-adhesive "plate" made would mean that it could be stuck to the bonnet between the headlights. You might need to remove the badge, and there's no guarantee that it would come off cleanly (plates aren't supposed to be easily removable). You may feel that's an option which could be retained with a new bumper — perhaps a special aftermarket one which doesn't have provision for the plate.

Fixing a number plate with cable ties or something similar makes it very easy for thieves to take, so they have double the time to spend on removing the rear plate.

Answer (score 1):

> I asked a police officer if I can remove the bumper and put a number plate in window and he said its illegal(is he right cos I've seen others do it).

I've seen others do that - it's not *legal* though, and you're asking for a fine of up to a **£1000**.

> If so where can I mount the number plate and be legally able to drive in uk? Can I, and is it possible to mount it on the radiator or somewhere else? I will eventually get the bumper fixed, but until I get it repaired, want a quick fix so I can drive it.

Mounting the number plate on the radiator or chassis cross member *may* give a suitable location from a visibility point of view - but it's largely irrelevant since driving the car around sans front bumper is illegal in of itself. It's stupid, it's dangerous and likely to draw justifiable attention from passing police.

There's *some* latitude around driving **directly** to a place of repair but that doesn't sound like you intend that, it sounds like you intend on driving around normally and that means you're opening yourself up prosecution under S40A of the Road Traffic Act to a mandatory 3 points, or potentially even a disqualification and a whopping great fine (up to £2.5k IIRC). A [cheap](https://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/283443378123) second hand bumper looks like much better value to me.

So don't be an idiot - get it fixed before you drive it.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what country, but since it looks like a RHD car I assume you mean the UK.

The regulations http://www.legislation.gov.uk/uksi/2001/561/part/II/made give the basic requirements as

- It should be mounted vertically or as near as practically possible
- It should be visible from any position in front of the car up to a distance of 22 meters, and at an angle up to 45 degrees either side of the plate's position (see the link for the exact details)
- There should be nothing in front of the plate which would impair taking a true photographic image of it.

A plate propped inside the windscreen probably fails point 1, and possibly points 2 and 3 if there are reflections from the windscreen itself.

Considering the size of a number plate, it may also be illegal by blocking some of the area of the windscreen depending where you position it.

Don't forget that the UK has many automatic number plate recognition cameras (not just "speed cameras") and many police cars are fitted with ANR which is "always on" to detect uninsured vehicles etc that are being used illegally, even when the police car is being used for some other purpose. If an ANR system can't read your number plate but a human looking at the captured image can figure it out well enough to identify the car (e.g. from part of the plate number plus the car model, paint colour, etc) you are living dangerously!

Comment: so it would be legal to remove the bumper and tie i to the horionntal metalbar as someone suggested?

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is drive the car away, I'd take the rally team approach to body repair.  Use a combination of zip ties and duct / elephant tape to temporarily reattach the bumper being careful not to obscure the headlight lens with the any tape.